# how to order Django query based on the sum of a specific field grouped by another field?

Tags: python, django

how to order Django query based on the sum of a specific field grouped by another field?

- The Model is simply recording goals that players score, every player has many inputs that each refers to a single goal.
- I'm trying to find out the top 3 scorers with the highest amount of goals scored.

Here is my model :

```py
class Goal(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    team = models.ForeignKey("teams.Team",on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey('players.PlayerProfile',related_name="goal_maker",on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
    assistant = models.ForeignKey('players.PlayerProfile',related_name="goal_assist",on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True,blank=True)
```

Now what I want to do is to group it by `player` field ordering it from `the highest player with goals` to `the lowest one`

**What I have tried**

I have tried to loop trough all my database entries for this model `Goal.objects.all()` and check if it is the same player I do `+=1` if not I create a new entry, and that is surly not the best way do achieve this.

Comment: Does something like this work? `PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(goals=Count('goal_maker')).order_by('-goals')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `PlayerProfile`s with the umber of goals, and then order by that number and slice, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(
    total_goals=Count('goal_maker')
).order_by('-total_goals')[:3]
```